# How to adjust the table in Latex?

Tags: tables

I am creating a table like this :

```
\begin{table}[htbp]
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa & bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb & cccccccccccccccc & ddddddddddddd & eeeeeeeeeeeee & & & & \\
    \hline
     erd & fds & 0 & 1470& MIN & 25th & 50th & 75th & MAX \\
     \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

How can I merge the last few blank cells with 'eee', and if the contents are long, the right part of the table will disappear, how can I adjust it? Many thanks.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! One way is to use the `tabularx` environment, to control the width of the table (this requires using at least one `X` column). Merging would be done through a`\multicolumn{5}{c}{eee}`.

Comment: Hi @Bernard thanks, could you please be more specific by 'control the width of the table (this requires using at least one X column)'? Please see my edit, the width of my table is too big and the right side is disappeared.

Comment: For your edit, you can load `makecell`, which allows for line breaks in standard cells.  I would write, for the first cell, something like `\makecell{Number of \\ distinct values}`. Other than that, you should post a short code, more representative of your real code.

Comment: @Cecilia, please extend your code fragment to complete small document. We now anything about your document layout. Also please provide real content of one row of table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    aaa & bbb & ccc & ddd & \multicolumn{5}{c|}{eee} \\
    \hline
    erd & fds & 0 & 1470& MIN & 25th & 50th & 75th & MAX \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi thanks, please see my edit, the width of my table is too big and the right side is disappeared, is there a way I can adjust it?

Comment: use a `tabularx` with the column specifier `X`. You'll find a lot of examples here

Answer (score 2):

You can use

`\multicolumn{5}{c}{eee}`

which will merge 5 cells.

Related to adjusting the visual appearance of tables in general there are packages such as  booktabs that will help you create good looking output.

Comment: You should show to OP how to use `booktabs`.  this will make more noticeably difference between yours and @user187802 answer.

Comment: Also note, that with `{c}` (instead of `{c|}`, the rightmost vertical line would be missing in the first row.